# iPhone static library distribution and release build errors (but not for debug)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

**Update**

Daniel was close, it just wasn't the search path. The **Prefix Header** under GCC 4.2 was set to:
$(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h

I missed that when I was combing through the first 2 times.
I removed it and now all is well.

---

**Original Question**

I have been using/building products with a static libraries for about a week now with no issues.

For the first time, I tried to make a distribution build (for ad hoc testing) and I am getting errors all over the place.

The errors, strangely say that it can't find Appkit headers. Which is odd because it is an iPhone app and shouldn't be linking to Appkit headers

Additionally, the library name, "libFJSCodeDebug.a" turns red while when I switch from debug to distribution/release. I figure this must be a big clue.

To test, I duplicated the debug configuration and renamed it release. This built fine. So it seems the problem is somewhere in the configuration. Below is a snippet of what I get in Xcode when I build. (Note: I named my target FJSCodeDebug even though it will be used for both debug and release builds)

```
Building target “FJSCodeDebug” of project “FJSCode” with configuration “Release” — (169 errors)
    Checking Dependencies
        cd /[redacted]/FJSCode
    setenv PATH "/DeveloperBeta/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/DeveloperBeta/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /DeveloperBeta/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch armv6 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -Os -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /DeveloperBeta/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -iquote /[redacted]/build/FJSCode.build/Release-iphoneos/FJSCodeDebug.build/FJSCodeDebug-generated-files.hmap -I/[redacted]/build/FJSCode.build/Release-iphoneos/FJSCodeDebug.build/FJSCodeDebug-own-target-headers.hmap -I/[redacted]/build/FJSCode.build/Release-iphoneos/FJSCodeDebug.build/FJSCodeDebug-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /U[redacted]/build/FJSCode.build/Release-iphoneos/FJSCodeDebug.build/FJSCodeDebug-project-headers.hmap -F/[redacted]/build/Release-iphoneos -I/[redacted]/build/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/coreyfloyd/Xcode/ProductionProjects/build/FJSCode.build/Release-iphoneos/FJSCodeDebug.build/DerivedSources/armv6 -I/[redacted]/build/FJSCode.build/Release-iphoneos/FJSCodeDebug.build/DerivedSources -c /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h -o /var/folders/R+/R+ofDLtuH1GOYQ1ZQ2C5mk+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppKit-gihvhjsfuggoevbehiszhgrzcska/AppKit.h.gch
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h:11:33: error: AppKit/AppKitDefines.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h:12:32: error: AppKit/AppKitErrors.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h:13:37: error: AppKit/NSGraphicsContext.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h:14:35: error: AppKit/NSAccessibility.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h:15:32: error: AppKit/NSActionCell.h: No such file or directory

...... (continues for everything in AppKit)......


Build failed (169 errors)
```

I'm looking for 1 of 2 solutions: 
Obviously, fix the release build to not get these errors
OR
Tweak the debug configuration to have all the important settings that a release configuration requires.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
-c /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h
```

leads me to believe your build target is trying to compile AppKit.h for some reason (while I don't think it should be doing that at all), and/or it's looking for it in the wrong place (i.e. in the root /System instead of in the SDK /Developer/Platforms/...).

You should double check your build settings library/frameworks search paths, and that AppKit.h isn't in the compile phase.

Comment: Thanks for the hint... It just wasn't where I expected it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Does your project include Mac OS products? Are you sure you haven't accidently included a Mac library/framework in your frameworks group?

In SDK2.2.1, I don't know why, but the thing that always gets me is when "Active SDK" and "Active Executable" become out of sync (in the build configuration dropdown). This leads to weird linker errors where the iPhone tries to *dynamically* link against its libraries. This setting seems to occasionally go out of sync whenever I switch from debug/release or device/simulator.

Perhaps its a similar case, its hard to tell without seeing the actual project settings.